# Xamarin In-App Billing Plugin subscription products for 1 month free promotion questions

Tags: ios, xamarin, in-app-purchase, promotions

I'd like to sell Subscriptions products on Apple.

And when Ios made a subscription product, I set up a monthly free promotion.

By the way, can't I check the payment for free for a month when I pay for the Subscription products with my Sandbox account?

I'm curious because if I pay for the subscription product with my sandbox account, I can't see the free payment for a month.

Or should I write something on the code shown below?

```
bool OnShouldAddStorePayment(SKPaymentQueue queue, SKPayment payment, SKProduct product)
{
     return true;
}
```

Comment: Are you using Non-renewing subscriptions or Auto-renewable subscriptions？

Comment: yes it is in use However, the Sandbox account is a newly created account. Even if I change my Sandbox account, if it is a group product that i have paid for at least once, do I not see the promotion!?